# How to indent tcl?

Tags: emacs, editor, tcl, text-editor, pretty-print

Before I take the emacs plunge, which, apparently, can [indent a region](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21749/can-emacs-beautify-existing-tcl-source-code) of tcl:

> The indent-region command is available from tcl-mode menu. You can
>   first do C-x h (mark-whole-buffer) to be able to indent the whole
>   buffer. – JeanPierre

Is this the only tool which can indent a region of tcl code?  Apparently tclhelp.net uses [naglfar](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9064); also, there's [frink(s)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2611).  But neither of these will actually **fix** indents?  What are the alternatives which will fix indents for at least a region of tcl?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "fixing" indents.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing indents"? How is the result from `indent-region` different than what you expect? If I have a block of poorly indented tcl code, I highlight it, and run `m-x indent-region`, the result is properly indented tcl code.

Comment: @Stefan yes, exactly the desired output.  Not sure how else to express it.